# How can I add together the numbers in a file?

Tags: c, while-loop, sum, numbers, fopen

I have a large text file. In this file there are some numbers I want to add together.

What I've tried:

```
int sum = 0, i = 0;
file = fopen(filename, "r");
while ((i = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
    if (isdigit(i)) {
        sum++;
    }
}
printf("Sum of numbers is: %i", sum);
fclose(file);
```

But that `isdigit(i)` is just a counter of how many digits this file contains, not what the sum of the numbers is.

The input is: `"This text 15 is very 19 nice."`
The result should be: `Sum of numbers is: 34`

Comment: Can you compute the *value* of a digit character?  How would you take a sequence of such values and compute the number they represent together?  How do you tell when such a sequence starts & stops?

Comment: `sum += i - '0';` but that's not `15 + 19`, it would be `1 + 5 + 1 + 9`.

Comment: This looks more like a question about parsing rather than about encoding. Which makes it a difficult one.

Comment: @dunno: you can accept one of the answers if it helped you by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 5):

## Consider the decimal placement

The missing part in the question's code is accumulating the digits (as opposed to counting the digits with `sum++;`) AND multiplying by ten the previous accumulated number before adding the next digit.

The answer is in:
`number = number * 10 + i - '0';`

The `- '0'` part is converting ASCII digit to a number.

Everything else in the below code is checks to make sure there are no obvious overflows and ***correctly*** supporting minus sign also adjacent to the numbers, as well as ignoring digits after the decimal point(s). I'm sure it is not perfect, but the idea here is to provide a working example of how it could be done, rather than a well tested code and using a library call to do it for you.

By popular demand (comments were deleted now) I've added a simple-but-working overflow check:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <error.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int sum = 0, state = 0, i = 0, dir = 1;
  unsigned int number = 0, check;
  if (argc < 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Missing filename\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  char* filename = argv[1];
  FILE* file = fopen(filename, "r");
  if (!file) {
    perror(filename);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  while (i != EOF) {
    i = fgetc(file);
    if (isdigit(i)) {
      if (dir) {
        state = 1;
        check = number;
        number = number * 10 + i - '0';
        if (check > number || number > INT_MAX) {
          fprintf(stderr, "Single number overflow error\n");
          fclose(file);
          return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
      }
    } else {
      if (state && dir) {
        check = number;
        if (dir < 0 && sum < 0)
          check -= sum;
        else if (dir > 0 && sum > 0)
          check += sum;
        if (check > INT_MAX) {
          fprintf(stderr, "Sum overflow error\n");
          fclose(file);
          return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        sum += number * dir;
        number = 0;
      }
      state = 0;
      dir = i == '-' ? -1 : i == '.' ? 0 : 1;
    }
  }
  printf("Sum of numbers is: %i\n", sum);
  fclose(file);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Test run:

```
$ cat opString.txt 
This text 15 is very 19 nice.
$ ./test2 opString.txt 
Sum of numbers is: 34
$
```

And just in case you are on 64bit linux system, and need much higher performance (you mentioned large file) the below code will map the entire file (even file larger than memory, the kernel will handle it nicely) and will not make a library call on every char. In my tests, `isdigit()` and `strtol()` slows it down significantly.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <error.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int addToSum(unsigned int* number, int* sum, int dir, FILE* file) {
  unsigned int check;
  check = *number;
  if (dir < 0 && *sum < 0)
    check -= *sum;
  else if (dir > 0 && *sum > 0)
    check += *sum;
  if (check > INT_MAX) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Sum overflow error\n");
    fclose(file);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  *sum += *number * dir;
  *number = 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int sum = 0, state = 0, i = 0, dir = 1;
  unsigned int number = 0, check;
  if (argc < 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Missing filename\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  char* filename = argv[1];
  FILE* file = fopen(filename, "r");
  if (!file) {
    perror(filename);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  if (fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END) < 0) {
    perror("fseek failed");
    fclose(file);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  long fsize = ftell(file);
  char* fmap = mmap(NULL, fsize, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fileno(file), 0);
  if (fmap == MAP_FAILED) {
    perror("map failed");
    fclose(file);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  long pos = 0;
  while (pos < fsize) {
    i = fmap[pos++];
    if (i >= '0' && i <= '9') {
      if (dir) {
        state = 1;
        check = number;
        number = number * 10 + i - '0';
        if (check > number || number > INT_MAX) {
          fprintf(stderr, "Single number overflow error\n");
          fclose(file);
          return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
      }
    } else {
      if (state && dir) addToSum(&number, &sum, dir, file);
      state = 0;
      dir = i == '-' ? -1 : i == '.' ? 0 : 1;
    }
  }
  if (state && dir) addToSum(&number, &sum, dir, file);
  printf("Sum of numbers is: %i\n", sum);
  fclose(file);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Input file name: `file.txt`

```
This text 15 is very 19 nice.
```

Output:

```
Sum of numbers is: 34
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
int sum = 0, num, i = 0;
int state = 0;
FILE* f;

    if ((f = fopen("file.txt", "r")) == NULL)
        return -1;

    while ((i = fgetc(f)) != EOF) {
        switch(state) {
        case 0: // processing text
            if (isdigit(i)) {
                num = i - '0';
                state = 1;
            }
            break;
        case 1: // processing number
            if (isdigit(i)) {
                num *= 10;
                num += i - '0';
            }
            else {
                sum += num;
                num = 0;
                state = 0;
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    if (state == 1) {
        sum += num;
    }

    printf("Sum of numbers is: %i\n", sum);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you mind adding an explanation as to what this is doing?

Comment: negative one is not an error return. You should use `EXIT_FAILURE` instead.

Comment: You could also do `if(!state) else`, if you want to.

Comment: I do not pretend that my code is error free. I show the way how to fix the problem about which the question was asked. The source code was talking about integers and there were no questions about overflowing integers.

Comment: Alright, that's fair. But still you should try to make it safe (and portable) if you can.

Comment: Thank you. Good advice. I will try.

Comment: The code will ignore the last number if there is no trailing delimiter after the last digit.

Answer (score 1):

*But that isdigit(i) is just a counter of how many digits this text contents but not whats the sum of the numbers is.*

Keep in mind, the function [isdigit()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgetc.htm) reads one character per call. So if it reads the character `9` for example, the value `sum` should grow by `i - '0'` (or 57 - 48, or 9).  And if there were two characters in sequence, such as `92`, reading one character at a time, the value `sum` would likewise be incremented by `9+2 -> 11`, not `92`.  Given this is what you want, here is how to do it:

The values you have determined are digits are actually [ASCII](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) values, so in viewing this table you can see all of the digits will have values from '0' to '9' (or in ASCII, 48 to 57).  So in your code you can simply change one line to sum up the value count:

```
int sum = 0;
    file = fopen(filename, "r");

    while ((i = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
        if (isdigit(i))
            sum += (i - '0');//subtract 48 from every 'i' verified as digit
                             //Sum will therefore add up values 
                             //between (48-48) to (57-48)
                             //(or between 0 to 9) 
        }
    printf(f,"Sum of numbers is: %i", sum);
fclose(file);
```

*However*, If you want to sum up numeric values represented by a sequence of digits within a buffer, then the code is different.  It would require keeping a flag as the buffer content is read.
*In pseudo code*:

```
char accumlator[10] = {0}; max possible sequential digits (change as needed)
int found = 0;//flag
int sum = 0;

 while ((i = fgetc(file)) != EOF) 
 {
    if (isdigit(i))
    {
        accumulator[found] = i;
        found++;
    }
    else
    {
        if(found != 0)
        {
            sum += atoi(accumulator);
            found = 0;
            accumulator[0] = 0;
            }
        }             
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `fgetc` only reads a single character that is a potential digit. It does not read a whole number that consist of several digits at once. If you want to read whole numbers, you must change the logic of your program. You can do one of the following:

1. Use fgetc as you do now and make your program assemble the individual digits into a number, by using the [ASCII Code](http://www.asciitable.com/) of the digits and converting that to a number using arithmetic. The numerical value of an individual ASCII character digit can be obtained using the expression `ascii_code - '0'`.
2. Use [fgets](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead to read a whole line at once and then use [strtol](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) to convert any digits you find into numbers.
3. Use [fscanf()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) to parse the file and extract the number in one step ([not recommended unless you know exactly what you are doing](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)).

Answer (score 1):

Your program only counts the number of digits in the file. Here is a simple solution using `getc()` to compute the number of all integral numbers in the file without the need for a state machine:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int count_numbers(const char *filename) {
    FILE *fp;
    unsigned long long total = 0, current = 0;
    int c;

    if ((fp = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot open input file %s\n", filename);
        return -1;
    }

    while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
            current = current * 10 + (c - '0');
        } else {
            total += current;
            current = 0;
        }
    }
    total += current; /* add the last number if at the very end of the file */
    printf("Sum of numbers is: %llu\n", total);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Notes:

- this program does not handle negative numbers, it ignores negative signs.
- it does not handle floating point numbers: processing `1.1` will produce a sum of `2`.
- very long numbers will produce the result modulo `ULLONG_MAX+1` but at least the behavior is defined.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add all the number strings up in this then you'll have to search for the digits and then convert them from a string to an integer using `strtol`. Here's how to do that:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define OVERFLOW_STR "Number cannot be represented in an int!\n"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *file;

    char n[12];
    char *p = n;
    int i = 0, sum = 0, tmp, old_errno;

    if(argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s file\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    file = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if(!file)
    {
        perror("Error opening file");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    while(i != EOF)
    {
        while( (i = fgetc(file)) != EOF &&
               i != '-' &&
               i != '+' &&
               !isdigit(i) )
        {
            /* empty loop */ ;
        }
        if(i != EOF)
        {
            do {
                if( p == n + sizeof(n) - 1 ||
                    ((*n != '-' || *n != '+') &&
                    p == n + sizeof(n) - 2) )
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Error: " OVERFLOW_STR);
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }
                *p++ = i;
            } while( (i = fgetc(file)) != EOF && isdigit(i) );
        }
        else
            break;

        *p = 0;

        old_errno = errno;
        errno = 0;
        tmp = strtol(n, NULL, 10);
        if( tmp == 0 && errno != 0 )
        {
            perror("Error converting string");
            break;
        }
        errno = old_errno;
        sum += tmp;
        p = n;
    }

    printf("Sum of numbers is: %d\n", sum);
    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

This is largely error-checked. There may be corner cases that I have left out.

Input (contained in a file whose name is passed as a command-line parameter):

> This text 15 is very 19 nice.

Output:

> Sum of numbers is: 34

Comment: Why the downvotes? If you have something to say to me, please do. I'm open to conversation.

Comment: I did not downvote, but the test for overflow is incorrect: `if( tmp == 0 && errno != 0)` will always fail. `tmp` has the value `LONG_MAX` or `LONG_MIN` in case of overflow. You don't need tp save `errno`, just set it to `0` before calling `strtol()` and check `if (errno != 0)` to detect overflow. Also note that legitimate numbers can have more than 11 digits, for example `00000000000000000000000001`.

Comment: Your attempt to handle negative numbers is interesting, but the code will fail to produce `0` for `1-1`.